# Trouble with with some key on keyboard

Tags: keyboard, debian-jessie

Colon key work randomly and my alt key only work if press twice. For alt+d or alt+tab i must press two time to work correctly.

I install again my OS (debian jessie) and all things fine for two week. and i now have same problem again

Comment: Do you have another keyboard which you can try? That would help isolate it to a software or hardware problem.

Comment: I checke another keyboard. its work fine. But after new installation my laptop keyboard work fine for two week and this is why im searching for software problem

Comment: Have you [configured the keyboard](https://wiki.debian.org/Keyboard) in a non-default way? Have you checked the disk drive - maybe the physical part of it that the keyboard driver is installed to is going flaky. It is more likely that there is some dirt in your keyboard and it simply needs to be cleaned.

Comment: Im use i3 desktop and add layout in /etc/default/keyboard by hand. I will clean my keyboard this week and ill check again